# Given a path to a directory how do I check if a certain file exisits therein?

Tags: c, file, path, server

So I'm given a `/path/to/a/directory/` and should check if `index.php` exists therein. If it does I should return `/path/to/a/directory/index.php`. If `index.html` exists instead i should return that, else `NULL`
Currently I am using `fopen(file, 'r')` but I dont think it does what I want it to do. I have also been looking into the functions `stat()` and `scandir()` but I am clueless on how I can use these... (even after reading the MAN pages over and over again ^^ )

```
/**
 * Checks, in order, whether index.php or index.html exists inside of path.
 * Returns path to first match if so, else NULL.
 */
char* indexes(const char* path)
{
    char* newPath = malloc(strlen(path) + strlen("/index.html") + 1);
    strcpy(newPath, path);

    if(access( path, F_OK ) == 0 )
    {
        printf("access to path SUCCESS\n");
        if( fopen( "index.php", "r" ))
        {
            strcat( newPath, "index.php" );
        }
        else if( fopen( "index.html", "r"))
        {
            strcat( newPath, "index.html" );
        }
        else
        {
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    return newPath;
}
```

My main problem that I see here is that I dont think that my functions looks for the files to `fopen()` inside the desired path. Where exactly does they look for the files? My root folder?

Any input would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: Checking if "/some/location/with/file" exists doesn't move your automagically to "/some/location/with", so you can do `fopen("file", "r")`. Do `fopen(path, "r")` instead.

Comment: but what file is it looking to open if i use `fopen(path, "r")`?

Comment: The same for which you used `access`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about opendir:

```
char* indexes(const char* path)
{
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *entry;
    char* newPath = NULL;

    dir = opendir(path);
    while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        if (!strcmp(entry->d_name, "index.php") || !strcmp(entry->d_name, "index.html"))
        newPath = malloc(strlen(path) + strlen(entry->d_name) + 2);
        sprintf(newPath, "%s/%s", path, entry->d_name);
        break;
    }
    closedir(dir);
    return newPath ;
}
```

Here you open the directory entry and scan it with `readdir` that returns a structure identifying each file inside (for more details see man page for `opendir` and `readdir`).
The use of `fopen` is to be discouraged because is heavy for the system that will try to open each file, and when the directory contains thousands or more file it will be very slow.

Comment: Alright! Im still quite new to this language though. Seems like you are calling a struct called `DIR` here? And what are you doing here `entry->d_name` exactly? Thank you!!

Comment: Your welcome. See answer update. For more details you can find them on man pages or on the net ;)

Answer (score 1):

your basic idea seen to be ok. Before you call fopen() construct the path/file name for each file. Allocate memory for the longest element and use it for e.g sprintf() to get your path. When fopen() succeeds you can return that pointer, if not don't forget to free() the memory.